# jquery how to correctly insert url in particular position at end of <li>

Tags: jquery

I am trying to insert a link at the end a list.  I actually got most of this figured out, but my last attempts have not been successful in getting two things to work correctly:

1. When the link is inserted, it is adding `[object Object]`.
2. Instead of inserting the link at the end of the list, it is overwriting the list `<li>` item.

Could anyone provide any guidance please?

```js
jQuery("#all-list ul:nth-child(1)").addClass("list-class-two");
jQuery(".list-class-two li:nth-child(5)").wrap( function() {
  
  var link = jQuery('<a/>');
  // console.log(link);
  link.attr('href', 'http://www.yahoo.com');
  link.text(jQuery(this).text('New Link Insert'));
  // console.log(link);
  return link;

} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="all-list">

  <ul class="list-group">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Milk</li>
    <li>Juice</li>
    <li>Soda</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="list-group">
    <li>orange</li>
    <li>yellow</li>
    <li>green</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: `link.text(jQuery(this).text('New Link Insert'));` could be `link.text(jQuery(this).text());` OR `link.text('New Link Insert');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append li first, then append a to the li, then set attributes and text for the link.

Here's a one-liner:

```
jQuery(".list-group").append(
    jQuery("<li/>").append(
        jQuery("<a/>").attr("href", "#").text("text")
    )
 );
```

Look at the brackets, a is append to li and attr/text are chained for a.

In case you want to add the link just for the first list, simply use :first like in

```
jQuery(".list-group:first").append(
    jQuery("<li/>").append(
        jQuery("<a/>").attr("href", "#").text("text")
    )
);
```

Comment: I think I am officially in AWE - amazing!  thank u so much - seems to work like a charm.